# Laravel document root set up for domain by cpanel - security threat?

Tags: php, cpanel, laravel

I have a Laravel installation on my shared hosting plan and they use CPanel.

When I set up the domain, I pointed it's document root to the Laravel public folder, and everything seems to be working okay.

Is this good practice? I've been told that it's not good to put it in the public_html folder at all, but if the server is only serving documents for that domain out of the public folder, is that the same thing as having it outside of the public_html folder?

I've set the domain up in cPanel to serve out of the /home/user/public_html/site.com/public.

I just want to make sure that it's secure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put all your files in /home/user, then put the contents of 'public' in /home/user/public_html and change $paths['public'] in the **bootstrap/paths.php** file to reflect this, as below:

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public_html',
```

Comment: Great solution, just did it and it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: I'm on a cheap shared hosting plan which does not give me access to place files in /home/user and only in the public folder...any work around? I'm using ipage.com